# Probability of a certain event happening at a particular day of the week

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a dataset that spans over a year in which I marked if a certain event happened on that day. With this information, is it possible for me to estimate the probability of that event happening in a given day?

For example, this is my dataset:

```
date        weekday   event_happened
2018-01-01  monday    true
2018-01-02  tuesday   false
2018-01-03  wednesday true
```

and so on.

If my goal is to calculate the probability of the event happening, let's say, next Monday by only using my dataset as features or evidence, do I just need to calculate

`(number of times event happened on Monday) / (amount of Mondays)`?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, assuming next Monday is 'typical' of the Mondays in your dataset. Maybe not if next Monday is a national holiday.

Comment: Hi @BruceET, thanks a lot. Mind if I ask something else? What if I also have the time when the event occurred in hour, and I want to know the probability of the event happening on Monday at 3pm. Do I need to multiply the probability of the event happening on Monday times the probability of the event happening at 3pm?

Comment: 'Exactly at 3pm' would be hard to model. If you mean '3:00 to 3:59' or '3:00 $\pm$ 15 min', then you might be able to make sense of it. But presumably you have less data on hour or half-hour intervals of time than on day-long intervals, so I wouldn't expect predictions to be as accurate.

Comment: Hi @BruceET, you are right, I meant from '3:00 to 3:59'. Also, this is for a pet project so the predictions don't have to be that accurate.